# onDraw method not drawing everything I put in to it

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I have created a custom view class to use in a project I'm working on. To put is simply, I'm displaying an image, then adding images on top of the original image (currently by clicking on the image, but that's not final).

I have these 2 methods in my custom view:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (Drawable d : drawableList)
    {
        d.draw(canvas);
    }
}

public void AddPoint(float x, float y)
{
    Drawable tempDrawable = pin;
    tempDrawable.setBounds((int)x, (int)y, (int)x + 50, (int)y + 50);

    drawableList.add(tempDrawable);

    invalidate();
}
```

The `AddPoint()` method is called in an `OnTouchListener` and is passes the coordinates of the `touch event`.

The way it currently works is it displays the main image, but will only display the most recent images where I clicked, previous ones just disappear.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: which class are you subclassing?

Comment: @Blackbelt Just the View class. I'm not sure if that's right though..

Comment: is the View visible? Was it added to a container ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes, when I run the program on my phone the large image is shown, but only the most recent "pin" added to the ArrayList is show on top of that image. It's a simple for-each loop, shouldn't it draw each item in the ArrayList?

Comment: ah, got it. If you want to draw more than one pin, you need more than one pin. You are just changing its bounds, but the drawable is always the same

Comment: But isn't that what I'm doing? declaring the tempDrawable as the pin variable (which holds the image of the pin) and adding that to the drawableList. That adds a Drawable to the list. Is that wrong?

Comment: how many pins do you want to show ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Ahh I've figured it out. I changed the line "Drawable tempDrawable = pin;" to "Drawable tempDrawable = mainRes.getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);". I got mainRes from the init(Context context) method.

Comment: I told you that 20 mins ago. I am glad that you fixed it though

Comment: @Blackbelt I did not understand what you were getting at until I figured it out, I was confused because the List was still being populated (I ran tests) but weasn't drawing them all.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what I was doing wrong.

The line of code:

```
Drawable tempDrawable = pin;
```

I changed to:

```
Drawable tempDrawable = mainRes.getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
```

I got mainRes from the init(Context context) method I wrote in the custom View class.